# BPAC SDK installed but showing CLSID not registered

Tags: c#, asp.net, brother-bpac

I installed the BPAC SDK however when I open the test project within to test the DLL it says the DLL is not registered. I looked in the register and show the CLSID there. Not sure what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In case you have WIN10 64bit launch project with target configuration platform from x64.